# Parsing File Delimited Vertically in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Calcimycin
AQ = AA 
MED = *62

*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Urinary Bladder
AQ = AB AH BS CH CY DE EM EN GD IM IN IR ME MI PA PH PP PS RA RE RI SE SU TR UL US VI
CX = consider also terms at CYST- and VESIC-
MED = *1359
```

Each record chunk has different number of lines, (e.g. `CX` entry does not always present).
But if `CX` exists, in only appear as 1 entry only.
We want to get a Hash that takes "MH" as keys and "CX" as values.

Hence parsing the above data we hope to get this structure:

```
$VAR = {  "Urinary Bladder" => ["CYST-" , "VESIC-"]};
```

What's the right way to parse it?

I'm stuck with this, that doesn't give me result as I want.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %bighash;
my $key = "";
my $cx = "";
while (<>) {

   chomp;

   if (/^MH = (\w+/)) {

      $key = $1;     
      push @{$bighash{$key}}, " ";
   }
   elsif ( /^CX = (\w+/)) {
      $cx = $1;

   }
   else {
      push @{$bighash{$key}}, $cx;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This becomes simpler if you use `$/` to read the data a paragraph at a time. I'm surprised that no-one else has suggested that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my %bighash;

$/ = '';

while (<DATA>) {
  if (my ($k) = /^MH = (.*?)$/m and my ($v) = /^CX = (.*?)$/m) {
    $bighash{$k} = [ $v =~ /([A-Z]+-)/g ];
  }
}

say Dumper \%bighash;

__DATA__
*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Calcimycin
AQ = AA 
MED = *62

*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Urinary Bladder
AQ = AB AH BS CH CY DE EM EN GD IM IN IR ME MI PA PH PP PS RA RE RI SE SU TR UL US VI
CX = consider also terms at CYST- and VESIC-
MED = *1359
```

The output looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Urinary Bladder' => [
                                 'CYST-',
                                 'VESIC-'
                               ]
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. And it's probably a good idea to examine the changes (or listen to Aki):

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %bighash;
my $current_key;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    chomp;

    if ( m/^MH = (.+)/ ) {
        $current_key = $1;

    } elsif ( /^CX = (.+)/ ) {
        my $text = $1;
        $bighash{ $current_key } = [ $text =~ /([A-Z]+-)/g ];

    }
}

print Dumper ( \%bighash );

__DATA__
*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Calcimycin
AQ = AA 
MED = *62

*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Urinary Bladder
AQ = AB AH BS CH CY DE EM EN GD IM IN IR ME MI PA PH PP PS RA RE RI SE SU TR UL US VI
CX = consider also terms at CYST- and VESIC-
MED = *1359
```

Update: Used Regex-Captures instead of `split` and `grep`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't practiced my perl kung fu lately but the last else statement looks fishy.

Try dropping the last else statement and add the 'push' statement straight after the second elsif. Basically do the push operation straight after matching the CX.

Also, you know that MH must always appear before a CX otherwise the logic breaks.

Answer (score 1):

- Fix the regular expressions
  `/^MH = (\w+/)` should be `/^MH (\w+)/`. You may want to use `\s+` or `\s*` instead of space
- Remove push from the `if` block
- Remove `else` block
- In the `elsif` block Push $cx into hash using the key $key
- List item
- Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your code

Try these and if you have difficulty i will help you with the code

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to use [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aTiny) or [Config::YAML](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aYAML) to do an initial pass over the file and then loop through each record individually.  Although if your file is like a gigabyte or more this might suck up all your memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I quickly did, I hope it gives you an idea to start from:

```
use Data::Dumper;
# Set your record separator
{
  local $/="*NEWRECORD\n";

  while(<DATA>) {
    # Get rid of your separator
    chomp($_);
    print "Parsing record # $.\n";
    push @records, $_ if ( $_ );
  }
}


foreach (@records) {
  # Get your sub records
  @lines = split(/\n/,$_);
  my %h = ();
  my %result = ();
  # Create a hash from your sub records
  foreach (@lines) {
    ($k, $v) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $_);
    $h{$k} = $v;
  }
  # Parse the CX and strip the lower case comments
  $h{ 'CX' } =~ s/[a-z]//g;
  $h{ 'CX' } =~ s/^\s+//g;
  # Have the upper case values as an array ref in the result hash
  $result{ $h{ 'MH' } } = [ split( /\s+/, $h{ 'CX' } ) ] if ( $h{ 'CX' } );
  print Dumper( \%h );
  print "Result:\n";
  print Dumper( \%result );
}
__DATA__
*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Calcimycin
AQ = AA 
MED = *62

*NEWRECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Urinary Bladder
AQ = AB AH BS CH CY DE EM EN GD IM IN IR ME MI PA PH PP PS RA RE RI SE SU TR UL US VI
CX = consider also terms at CYST- and VESIC-
MED = *1359
```